# I can't quite tell why my message box is disabled

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, design

Was viewing a message on Careers, and the message box was disabled. It displayed a big red box below it, but it was empty. I assumed it was an error box that was supposed to tell me why I couldn't submit another message:

[image: Standard appearance of box]

Turns out, highlighting all the text proves I'm right:

[image: The hidden text in the box]

Perhaps don't use red text on a red background?

Comment: The red means it's important. The extra red means it's EXTRA-IMPORTANT!

Comment: Someone [made a CSS mistake](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tQH9h.png) setting both background color and fore color to the same value.

Comment: We'll remedy this...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Okay, all fixed on our next push.

Comment: COME ON, DATA...

Comment: Wow i had no idea GIFs played on the Android app.

Comment: Feel like you should know that, @KasraRahjerdi.

Comment: @stevvve i mean, i do *now*. Mario Kart?